# JPA @Id annoation

Tags: jpa

i want to insert into a table with a specified value,but it just don't work,
 here is my code:

```
@Id
@Column(insertable=true,updatable=true)
public Long getS_id() {
    return s_id;
}


@Resource(name="studentService")
private StudentService stus;

Student student = new Student();
    student.setS_id(123213L);
    student.setName("vincent");
    stus.add(student);
```

If I change:

```
@Id
@Column(insertable=true,updatable=true)
public Long getS_id() {
    return s_id;
}
```

to this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(insertable=true,updatable=true)
public Long getS_id() {
    return s_id;
}
```

and don't set `s_id` manualy it works well.

here my student class

```
@Entity()
@Table(name="stu_info")
public class Student implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
/**
 * 学生的学号
 */
private Long s_id;
/**
 * 学生姓名
 */
private String name;
/**
 * 学生性别
 */
private String sex;
/**
 * 学生生日
 */
private Date birthday;

/**
 * 学生电话号码
 */
private String telephone;
/**
 * 学生所在年级
 */
private String grade;
/**
 * 学生所在班级
 */
private String classes;
/**
 * 学生编号
 */
private int number;
/**
 * 学生父亲姓名
 */
private String father_name;
/**
 * 学生母亲姓名
 */
private String mother_name;
/**
 * 学生个人疾病史
 */
private String diseases_history;

@Id
@Column(insertable=true,updatable=true)
public Long getS_id() {
    return s_id;
}
public void setS_id(Long s_id) {
    this.s_id = s_id;
}
@Column(length=32)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Column(length=12)
public String getSex() {
    return sex;
}
public void setSex(String sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
public Date getBirthday() {
    return birthday;
}
public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
    this.birthday = birthday;
}

@Column(length=12)
public String getTelephone() {
    return telephone;
}
public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
    this.telephone = telephone;
}
@Column(length=32)
public String getGrade() {
    return grade;
}
public void setGrade(String grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}
@Column(length=32)
public String getClasses() {
    return classes;
}
public void setClasses(String classes) {
    this.classes = classes;
}
@Column(length=32)
public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}
@Column(length=32)
public String getFather_name() {
    return father_name;
}
public void setFather_name(String father_name) {
    this.father_name = father_name;
}
@Column(length=32)
public String getMother_name() {
    return mother_name;
}
public void setMother_name(String mother_name) {
    this.mother_name = mother_name;
}
@Column(length=32)
public String getDiseases_history() {
    return diseases_history;
}
public void setDiseases_history(String diseases_history) {
    this.diseases_history = diseases_history;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of code outlining your Student object so that we can see your JPA annotations on it?

Comment: "Won't work" is a bit vague, don't you think? Could you supply the error you're getting if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: is "s_id" column is primary key in your table? If so you should get some error as data base will not allow null into primary key column.

Comment: There could be a million things wrong. The database might have a constraint, there might not be connection to the database, you may not have enough space in the hard drive, etc etc.. If you don't show the error log, nobody can help you. And nobody should be trying to help you either.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information posted I would guess you are using SQL Server and to insert a record into an SQLServer table with an explicit value defined for an Identity column requires you to turn on identity inserts for that table.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188059.aspx

So if you run the above against your table you should then be able to persist using a specific value.

So not really anything to do with JPA.

Answer (score 0):

You have marked s_id with @Id which tells Spring that the field is the primary key. The reason it works with GenerationType.IDENTITY is because it lets spring assign an ID to the entity at the time of persistence. It would be better if you use an ID generation strategy rather than manually entering when doing so I would suggest you use GenerationType.SEQUENCE and let the database handle the ID generation. please refer : https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers